# Algorithm for the implementation of merge sort using link array(pointers)

Tags: c#, c, pointers, merge, mergesort

```
 int a[SIZE];
 int link[SIZE];              
 
 int MergeLists(int i, int j)
 {
 int head;
 int *pprev = &head;                  
     while((i != -1) && (j != -1)){      
         if(a[i] <= a[j]){               
             *pprev = i;                 
             pprev = &link[i];           
             i=*pprev;                   
         } else {                        
             *pprev = j;                 
             pprev = &link[j];           
             j=*pprev;                   
         }
     }
     if(i == -1)                         
         *pprev=j;                       
     else                                
         *pprev=i;
 
     printf("%d head",head);                    
     return head;
 }
 
 int MergeSort(int low, int end)
 {
 int mid, i, j;
     if((end - low) == 0){               
         return low;                     
     }
     if((end - low) == 1){               
         link[low] = -1;                 
         return low;                     
     }
     if((end - low) == 2){               
         if(a[low] <= a[end-1]){         
             link[low]   = end-1;        
             link[end-1] = -1;
             return low;                 
         } else {                       
             link[end-1] = low;          
             link[low]   = -1;
             return end-1;               
         }
     }
     mid = (low+end)/2;                  
     i = MergeSort(low, mid);            
     j = MergeSort(mid, end);           
     return MergeLists(i, j);            
 }
 
 int main()
 {
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
     {
         printf("\nenter element number %d: ",i+1);
         scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     }
     i = MergeSort(1, SIZE);
     do{
         printf("%3d", a[i]);
         i = link[i];
     }while(i != -1);
     return 0;
 }
```

to implement merge sort using link array(pinters)
error is given below
input 4 5 2 1
output 1 2 5
MergeLists() uses head for the start of a list (the old code uses link[0]), and -1 for the end of a list (the old code uses 0). This allows sorting of a[0] to a[n-1] (the old code was sorting a[1] to a[n], with a[0] unused).

Comment: What data exactly have you used for input and what output did you get? Have you tried to identifiy where in your algorithm things go wrong? Adding some code for tracing algorithm decisions might give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be a minor problem, just change the function call in `main` to

```cpp
i = MergeSort(0, SIZE);
```

In C or C++, the index starts with 0, and it is also true when we try to write a function.